# Pass variables to JavaScript functions context

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often use a construct like this:

```
var $this, url, callback; //some private vars
loadCallback = function($that, url, callback) {
    return function(responseText, textStatus, req) {
        ...
    };
})($this, url, callback)
```

However that is not quite comfortable. Is there some alternative?
I already took a look at jQuery.proxy, but that functions seems to fix the "this" variable so loadCallback can not get called applying another "this" context.

Comment: There are other ways to do it, but they all generally do the same thing. Either you change the context, pass an additional parameter, or store it in a parent scope (or any scope that the child scope has access to)

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Implement your own simple version like this:

```
function bind(fn, _this) {
    var _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2); 
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(_this, _args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var loadCallback = bind(function(url, responseText, textStatus, req) {
    console.log(url, responseText)
}, this, url);
```

A more complete [polyfill can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

Comment: what browsers are supported?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility